# Add a class to an icon after click input radio

Tags: javascript, css, click, icons, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add a class to an element when an input radio is checked or clicked. I have two inputs radios with visibility hidden and I've put a  FontAwesome icon inside a label. The problem is that the browser console tells me Cannot read property addEventListener of null. I know I should be doing something wrong but I'm not very expert with Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
  function changeColorArrowUp() {
    var iconArrowUp = document.getElementById('arrow-puja-ascendent');
    var iconArrowDown = document.getElementById('arrow-puja-descendent');
    iconArrowDown.classList.remove("light");
    iconArrowUp.classList.add("light");
  }

  var inputArrowUp = document.getElementById('ascendentOrder');
  inputArrowUp.addEventListener("click", changeColorArrowUp, false);
</script>

<div class="wrapper-title-range">
  <p class="text-title-range">Rango valoración</p>
  <p class="wrapper-inputs-arrows">
    <input type="radio" class="order-results" name="rangoPuja" id="ascendentOrder" value="ascendentOrder">
    <label for = "descendentOrder"><i id="arrow-puja-ascendent" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" class="order-results" name="rangoPuja" id="descendentOrder" value="descendentOrder">
    <label for = "ascendentOrder"><i id="arrow-puja-descendent" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: One does not click a radio button, one changes a radio button

Comment: Also, the script is running before the elements are available, you should move it to the bottom, right before `</body>`

Comment: You were right¡ It works right now but an event change is a problem because change means enable and disable radio button. And I need changeColorArrowUp to happen just if the radio button is enabled. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You were totally right. It works like a cosmic puzzle right now. Thanks a lot¡¡